# SQL QUERY for a SQLSERVER 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `Product` and `images`.
The values in the two tables are given below

```
SELECT * FROM ProductTable
```

Structure is (Productid, Categoryid, ProductName)

```
1   1   Product1
2   1   Product2
3   2   Product2
4   2   Product3
5   2   Product4

SELECT * FROM ImageTable
```

Structure is (ImageID, ProductID, ImageName)

```
1   1   Image1
2   1   Image2
3   2   Image3
4   2   Image4
5   4   Image5
6   5   Image6
```

My query is :

```
SELECT ImageTable.ProductID, ImageName 
FROM ImageTable 
LEFT JOIN ProductTable ON ImageTable.ProductID=ProductTable.ProductID 
GROUP BY ImageTable.ProductID, ImageName
```

The result is :

```
1   Image1
1   Image2
2   Image3
2   Image4
4   Image5
5   Image6
```

But I want the result as (i.e. the First Imagename of the Productid from the imagetable)

```
1       Image1
2       IMage3
4       Image5
5       Image6
```

Comment: Is "first" defined as the row with the lowest `ImageId` value? Because tables, by definition, do not *have* an order.

Answer (score 3):

Really `LEFT JOIN` with `ProductTable` is unnecessary. So try this one -

```
SELECT ProductID, ImageName
FROM (
     SELECT 
            i.ProductID
          , i.ImageName
          , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.ProductID ORDER BY i.ImageName)
     FROM dbo.ImageTable i
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Or try this -

```
SELECT 
       i.ProductID
     , ImageName = MIN(i.ImageName)
FROM dbo.ImageTable i
GROUP BY i.ProductID
```

Output -

```
ProductID   ImageName
----------- ---------
1           Image1
2           Image3
4           Image5
5           Image6
```

Comment: I just used `MIN()` without understanding his actual query. +1 for taking time to answer and proving simple queries.

Comment: Thanks. @hims056, can you undelete your answer? I can't up-vote it.

Comment: @hims056, but you can always improve it.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ImageTable.ProductID, MIN(ImageName)
FROM ImageTable 
LEFT JOIN ProductTable ON ImageTable.ProductID=ProductTable.ProductID 
GROUP by ImageTable.ProductID
```

Comment: it sql server you must put column that are in select list either in group by or aggregate function t otherwise it give u error

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ProductID, MIN(ImageName) 
     FROM 
       ImageTable 
GROUP by ProductID
```